Unable to upload images to server in Flutter. returning URL as url/filename.octet-stream"
I am able to get the images I need from the device, but when I try to upload it it returns an octet-stream, which I found out is for arbitrary data. I don't really know what that means.
Below are my functions for getting the images and video the user wants to upload:
 XFile? cameraImagePath;
  List<File> galleryImages = [];
  XFile? galleryVideoPath;
  final ImagePicker _imagePicker = ImagePicker();

  // Function to take a single picture with the camera
  Future<void> takePicture() async {
    final XFile? image = await _imagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
    );

    if (image != null) {
      cameraImagePath = image;
      // item.image = image;
      update();
    }
  }

  // Function to select a maximum of 3 pictures from the gallery
  Future<void> selectImages() async {
    final List<XFile>? images = await _imagePicker.pickMultiImage();

    if (images != null &&
        images.length <= 3 &&
        galleryImages.length + images.length <= 3) {
      galleryImages.addAll(images.map((e) => File(e.path)).toList());
      // item.images = galleryImages.map((file) => file).toList();
      update();
    } else {
      Get.snackbar('Error', 'Select a maximum of 3 images');
    }
  }

  // Function to select only one video from the gallery
  Future<void> selectVideo() async {
    final XFile? video = await _imagePicker.pickVideo(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );

    if (video != null) {
      galleryVideoPath = video;
      // item.video = video;
      update();
    }
  }

  // Function to upload all media (image and video) to the server
  Future<void> uploadMedia() async {
    _isLoading = true;
    update();

    try {
      if (cameraImagePath != null) {
        File file = File(cameraImagePath!.path);
        var response = await CreateTransactionAPIs.uploadFile(file);
      }

      for (File image in galleryImages) {
        var response = await CreateTransactionAPIs.uploadFile(image);
      }

      if (galleryVideoPath != null) {
        File video = File(galleryVideoPath!.path);
        var response = await CreateTransactionAPIs.uploadFile(video);
      }

      Get.snackbar('Success', 'Media uploaded successfully');
    } on SocketException {
      Get.snackbar('Error', 'No internet connection');
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar('Error', 'Failed to upload media');
    } finally {
      _isLoading = false;
      update();
    }
  }

Here below is my API function itself where the upload is carried out. what do i need to do to get it to work?
static Future<void> uploadFile(File file) async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(_uploadUrl));

    // Add file to the request
    request.files.add(
      http.MultipartFile(
        'file',
        file.readAsBytes().asStream(),
        file.lengthSync(),
        filename: basename(file.path),
      ),
    );

    try {
      var response = await request.send();

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
        var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);
        print('Upload successful: $responseString');
        print(jsonDecode(responseData.toString()));
        return jsonDecode(responseData.toString());
      } else {
        print('Upload failed: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
      }
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      print('SocketException: $e');
      // Handle SocketException, e.g., show a snackbar
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      // Handle any other exceptions
    }
  }

any help or advice will be very much appreciated. I have been on this for a long time now.
I have uploaded the files directly from my post man, so I know the URL works.

Here's how you can modify the code:
request.files.add(
  http.MultipartFile(
    'file',
    file.readAsBytes().asStream(),
    file.lengthSync(),
    filename: basename(file.path),
    contentType: getContentType(file), // New line
  ),
);

String getContentType(File file) {
  String extension = extension(file.path);
  switch (extension) {
    case '.jpg':
    case '.jpeg':
      return 'image/jpeg';
    case '.png':
      return 'image/png';
    case '.gif':
      return 'image/gif';
    case '.mp4':
      return 'video/mp4';
    // Add more cases for other video formats if needed
    default:
      return 'application/octet-stream'; // Fallback for unknown types
  }
}


This worked for me. Thank you very much. A little correction had to be made, however. I had to change contentType: getContentType(file) to contentType: MediaType.parse(getContentType(file) the MediaType.parse() is from the http_parser package [https://pub.dev/packages/http_parser]
